# error 60 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate-paypal-laravel

Tags: laravel, ssl, curl, paypal, openssl

my problem is when i clicked to a shopping cart button and after fulling information for checkout process. i got this error before display paypal page.

**error 60 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate-paypal-laravel**
after some research i figure out that maybe is related to cURL so i download file and add path in php.ini file like below:

```
curl.cainfo =  "C:\wamp\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile= "C:\wamp\cacert.pem"
```

i verified php_curl is activated.
but it is not working. i restart apache serve and re-run php command serve but nothing changed.

Any help !!

PS: i'm working on localhost
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: no, i already checked this link. even after modifying CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false, nothing changed for me